# Appium android device on OS X won't start

Tags: android, testing, appium, device, ui-automation

I'm using Appium 1.6.3 via terminal and IntelliJ for my test cases. Now, I have an app in which I need to test some UI inserting, and I'd like to do so in automatic. 
Here's my code

```
public class Register {
private AppiumDriver driver;


@Before
public void setup() throws MalformedURLException {


    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("device","Android");

    //mandatory capabilities
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("udid","my udid");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.1.1");
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage","app-package");

    //activity
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "app-activity");



    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("https://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
}


@Test
public void register(){
    WebElement barraBianca=driver.findElement(By.id("element id after the /"));
    barraBianca.click();
    barraBianca.sendKeys("0000000000");
    WebElement verify=driver.findElement(By.id("id"));
    verify.click();
}
```

}

That's my problem. I start the server typing Appium in terminal and then executing my whole program in IntelliJ, but I get the error "process finished with error 255" and the string

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
```

related to the driver=new AndroidDriver (etc etc)

Where am I wrong?

Really thank you guys